# How to allow a particular view controller to support for both landscape and portrait orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

My application is navigation based application which is supporting iOS 6. Except a view controller all others will support only portrait mode. Particular view controller alone has to support both landscape and portrait orientations.

I searched lot there are tons of questions for this but none of the answer is suitable for me. If some one knows, kindly guide me

I set the orientation as **Portait** in Project -> Targets -> Summary -> Supported orientation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should use methods for the iOS6 presented in [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you are making your app for iOS6. Orientation method like `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in iOS6, alternate method for iOS6 is `shouldAutoRotate`. You should only use the old method if your app is supporting also iOS5.

Second If you are using `UINavigationcontroller` in your application and you need to have different interface orientations then navigationController could mess up the interface orientation in the application. Possible solution (worked for me) is to implement a custom `UINavigationController` and override the interface orientation methods within that custom `UINavigationController` class, this will make your viewControllers rotate according to the orientation you set because your controllers are pushed from the `UINavigationController`. Don't forget to add those methods in your particular viewController also.

**CustomNavigationController.h**

```
@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

**CustomNavigationController.m**

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController

//overriding shouldRotate method for working in navController
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{  
  return   [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];   
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
   return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

Comment: do i need to add above methods in all the view controllers or that particular view controller alone

Comment: you should add in the viewControllers where you want to change the orientation. as your application would be changing orientation so it is best to add in all viewcontrollers and just set the particular orientation what you want for that view controller.

Comment: i added above methods in my view controllers but when i am rotating my device ,CustomNavigationController methods are not all calling. if possible can you please tel me how to override that class. i just import that class

Comment: I hope your answer will work but i am facing problem while overriding custom navigation controller methods. What should i do in particular view controller class to support both orientation

Comment: You should set your CustomNavigationController to your default navigationController , when you add the navigationController on UIWindow then you should use your customNavigationController.

Comment: can you please what work should be done in the view i want to rotate

Answer (score 0):

I really think that the correct way to do it is to set both landscape and portrait as supported orientations, and not allowing a change in the orientation on the VC you don't want to rotate, by returning NO on the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

if the orientation that was passed to the method was not supposed to be supported.

As mentioned in the comments, this method can no longer be used. You should use :

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
```

And find out the current orientation inside this function and returning NO if you don't want to rotate.

Comment: @Mppl `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated for iOS6.  It does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to allow your application different Orientations!

otherwise nothing from above will work

Set it in project target on General under Deployment Info section:

[image]