# iPad App Orientation not changed in ios 6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, orientation

I developed ipa app in both orientations but but `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {return YES;}`
not called.

Comment: Are you using navigationController?

Comment: Yes.I am using UINavigationController

Comment: Did you go to your app target, Summary tab and ensure all of the supported orientations are selected?

Answer (score 1):

Using `UINavigationController` can disturb the orientation of `viewControllers`, to make it work, you can implement a custom NavigationController and use it in your application. You should also make sure that you are not adding subview to your window, if you use `subView` to your `UIWindow` then you will get a warning on the console. `Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`, your orientation methods would not be called if you use `subview` . Right way to do is

```
self.window.rootViewController = yourRootController;
```

[Follow my answer for implementing UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808532/how-to-allow-a-particular-view-controller-to-support-for-both-landscape-and-port/15808746#15808746)  it will solve your problem.